# Writint to a .txt file with php in unix enviroment where file need root permisions

Tags: php, unix, file-io, file-permissions

<s>okay now this is utterly bewildering to me and I can't figure out why this script is not working</s>  basically I am attempting to write a line of data to a .txt file in php 
here is the part of the script which matters:

```
    set_include_path('/etc/apache2/rewrite/');
    if($_GET['type']=="14"){ //video is documentary
         $file = '/etc/apache2/rewrite/Documentaries.txt';
         $line= clean_url($content[0]['title']) . " " . $content[0]['content_id'] ."\n";
         file_put_contents($file, $line, FILE_APPEND);

            echo "inseted into documentaries <br>" . $line;
    }else if ($_GET['type']=="17"){//video is a talk
         $file = '/etc/apache2/rewrite/Talks.txt';
         $line= clean_url($content[0]['title']) . " " . $content[0]['content_id'] ."\n";
         file_put_contents($file, $line, FILE_APPEND);
            echo "inseted into talks";

    }else if($_GET['type']=="15"){//video is debate
         $file = '/etc/apache2/rewrite/Debates.txt';
         $line= clean_url($content[0]['title']) . " " . $content[0]['content_id'] ."\n";
         file_put_contents($file, $line, FILE_APPEND);
                            echo "inseted into debates";
   }
```

and note that after this block i echo the `$line` which is something like this

```
   inside-nature-s-giants-the-leatherback-turtle 13443
```

and also the `echo`'s inside the if statement are also echoe'd however nothing is  modified in any of the files for a reason I can't seem to figure out I have given the script both write and execute permission and still can't seem to get this to work .. <s>I am unsure what is going on As I use similar logic in other scripts without problem</s> any help would be greatly greatly appreciated as I've sworn at my terminal a little to much for my liking 
Thanks, 
Brendan

---

**Update ** I do not have the correct file permisions thanks to @SyntaxLAMP for reminding me to check error logs

okay here is the permision for the php file

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9202 Jan 25 07:48 update_untagged.php
```

and the permisions of the three files I am attempting to write to

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      7 Jan 25 05:05 Debates.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110691 Jan 25 07:16 Documentaries.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  45747 Jan 25 05:05 Talks.txt
```

they both have the same permisions so I dont understand why this still isn't working any help with this would be greatly appreciated stil

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Do you have error logging turned on?

Comment: None which I can see though this it is throught an html form ... didnt even think to check the logs ... brb

Comment: Okay yes I am getting a permission denied error , when trying to open the file ... is there any way to run a php script accesed from html as as root? as the script already has -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: You may need to give whatever user is running the PHP script access to the files, not just the script.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP was just updating check the update should the file not have these permisions already? if not how can i grant them

Comment: For what evil reason you want to access to a root file ?
If you want to access it, make it a non root file, but never access to a root file from a non-CLI PHP script.

Comment: @Loenix non-cli php script? not sure exatly what that means .. the script in question is password protected and only accesible by sysadmin.. it needs to be a root file because the .txt files are used for apache rewrite module mapping, unless there's another way to do this I kinda stuck ... if you know of one please share as I would love it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the user the script is running as access to those files. You can either give everyone access to them like this:

```
chmod 666 Debates.txt Documentaries.txt Talks.txt
```

Or set the owner to whatever the script runs as (possibly www-data):

```
chown www-data Debates.txt Documentaries.txt Talks.txt
```

Edit:

Just to be clear, don't give everyone access unless there's a valid reason to do so, it's a lot safer just to change the owner to whatever the script runs as.

Comment: thanks a ton ... the script itself is login/ password protected and is only accessible by me the adin right now is this what you mean by `don't give everyone access` ... my reasoning as explained above is this script allows me to categories content and the .txt files are need for the apache rewrite module ... and I really can't think of another way to do this although my current solution i am aware is not hardened

Comment: By don't give access to everyone I meant that the chown method is safer than the chmod one. If this server is only used by you it's not really an issue, but if it's a shared server and you don't want other people to be able to edit the files or script then you don't want to give everyone write permissions (which chmod 666 does).

Comment: the server is only accessed threw me ie. via a terminal with ssh,  but this will be a live website at some point in the future. should this  be something I address before launching the site?

Comment: As long as it's not a shared server (i.e. multiple people have ssh access, and you don't trust them) it will be fine.